# Apply different flow in the same container with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to have the `h1` element to the top of the container, on the center, with `column` direction. How do I align it?

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gsg/pen/yYJyNb)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">  
  <h1>Description</h1>

<figure class="gallery-item">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <figcaption class="img-title">
    <h5>Image Title</h5>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="gallery-item">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <figcaption class="img-title">
    <h5>Image Title</h5>
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="gallery-item">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <figcaption class="img-title">
    <h5>Image Title</h5>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container { 
  display: flex;     
  flex-direction: row;  
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
  background: grey;   
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used display:flex to align your items, and h1 came under flex. This is why it was aligned with the items.

```
.container { 
  display: flex;     
  flex-direction: row;  
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;  
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
.wrapper {
 background:grey;
}
h1 {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[check solution here](http://codepen.io/sachya/pen/RWRNrz)